# Upgrading Youtrack

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

I want to ask a question about upgrading from one version of youtrack to another. Is this an appropriate question for this site?

I did a search for "youtrack" and 8 results came back, none of them have been closed and none have negative scores, I've checked the tour page and it has the following entry:

> Don't ask about...
>
> **Anything in a home or development environment**

This makes me want to check if asking about a youtrack upgrade is acceptable, I do not use youtrack in a home environment, but I do use it to aid development, I'm not aware of when this rule was put in place and it might be that when those questions were asked, the tour page did not have the rule, so, does this mean that any further questions regarding youtrack are off topic?

In my particular situation I have a server room at my office where I have youtrack installed on a virtual machine.

My question is not about maintaining virtual machines, it is purely about upgrading from one version of youtrack to another, I have found that the documentation is not as as complete as it perhaps could be with regards to upgrading.

Comment: To specifically address your question, if Youtrack is supporting production staff (eg, developers) then the question can be on-topic here. The "development environment" exclusion is mainly against software and configurations that are unsupportable and primarily used by developers as an assessment of what might be supportable (eg running a WAMP stack on your local workstation for initial development of a webapp; WAMP is pretty solidly off-topic here, but if you setup a proper LAMP stack for the webapp that would be on-topic [even though they're pretty close to the same thing]).

Answer (score 7):

A better question than "Can I ask my question here" is "where can I get good answers". I'm not convinced you will get good answers for questions about youtrack here. While there might be a few questions here, the questions and the few answers they have are of low quality.

Comment: Yeah, why not go to the vendor's forums (http://www.jetbrains.com/devnet/youtrack/)?